# How to setup Apache for Phalcon PHP INVO demo application?

Tags: php, phalcon

I would like to run INVO https://github.com/phalcon/invo but I can't figure out how to setup Apache to serve its content. After cloning github repo, I got 2 `.htaccess` files, one in project's root and other in public subdirectory.

### This is my Apache config (/etc/apache2/sites-available/010-invo.conf)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName invo.l
        ServerAlias www.invo.l
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /workspace/invo
        <Directory /workspace/invo>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /workspace/invo/error.log
        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /workspace/invo/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

With this configuration I can't get HTML links to work properly - all CSS and JS files are not loaded (they have  paths begining with `invo`) but app is served from the root of local domain (http://invo.l).

What is wrong with my config?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just nested cloned github project into another directory (invo). Now it's /workspace/invo/invo - and it is working

Answer (score 1):

In the default invo installation the basePath is /invo/ so when you installed that second invo in a subdirectory you just got lucky.

The trick is to find out why you got lucky.
Can you open up config/config.php and see if you can explain that for yourself. Does that contain a reference to invo?

Also check the .htaccess in /public does that contain a reference to invo?